# Call Web Api action with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#send").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3484/api/mail/send/',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: 'some_email@test.com'
    });
  });
});
```

And the Web API action is:

```
[Route("api/mail/send"), HttpPost]
public void Send([FromBody]String email) {
}
```

The action is called but the email is null.

What am I missing?

Comment: But i ser the data type as text. Wouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#send").on("click", function () {
    var data={email :'some_email@test.com'};

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3484/api/mail/send/',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      data:  JSON.stringify(data)
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#send").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3484/api/mail/send/',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: { email: `some_email@test.com' },
    });
  });
});
```

`data` must be JSON object. Alternative for `$.ajax` is `$.post`. It has documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/